# PGFPlots histogram not showing all series

Tags: pgfplots

I've to do a (simple) histogram using PGFPlots, but I don't know why it doesn't shows all the series on the X-Axis.

Minimal working example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      x tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
      ylabel={\small{Efficienza (\milli\gram\per\gram)}},
      width = 15.4cm, height = 10.7cm,
      legend style={
        font=\scriptsize,
        cells={anchor=west}
      },
      legend pos=north west,
      symbolic x coords={Spugna 1,Spugna 2,Spugna 3,Spugna 4,Spugna 5,Spugna 6},
      xtick=data,
      tick label style={font=\scriptsize},
      ybar interval=0.7,
    ]
    \addplot coordinates {(Spugna 1,0.56) (Spugna 2,2.84) (Spugna 3,3.57) (Spugna 4,5.45) (Spugna 5,1.12) (Spugna 6,4.29)};
    \addplot coordinates {(Spugna 1,0.66) (Spugna 2,3.10) (Spugna 3,3.77) (Spugna 4,5.61) (Spugna 5,1.27) (Spugna 6,4.27)};
    \legend{Reali,Fitting}
  \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

There are clearly 6 series, but PGFPlots only show 5 of them:

[image: Wrong plot with only 5 series]

However, if I put `ybar` instead of `ybar interval=0.7`, all the series are typesetted (but in an ugly plot):

[image: Correct plot but ugly bars]

**How can I fix that?**

Comment: What do you think is ugly on the second image? I guess you mean the white space between the bars. To reduce that you can either change the `bar width` to a value that fits your needs or you can change the `width` of the `axis` environment.

Comment: @stefan-pinnow I will try it, thank you!

Comment: It doesn't show all the bars in the first one, because that is what `ybar interval` is designed to do, read the description of it in the `pgfplots`  manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I want to write a proper answer to this, for future reference.

It turns out that, actually, I wasn't unable to find the right thing in the ginormous PGFPlot manual :) so I've fixed it (thanks Stefan) using `ybar` *and* `bar width = .8cm`.

[image: Solved! Correct histogram]

Final code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      x tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
      ylabel={\small{Efficienza (\milli\gram\per\gram)}},
      width = 15.4cm, height = 10.7cm,
      legend style={
        font=\scriptsize,
        cells={anchor=west}
      },
      legend pos=north west,
      symbolic x coords={Spugna 1,Spugna 2,Spugna 3,Spugna 4,Spugna 5,Spugna 6},
      xtick=data,
      tick label style={font=\scriptsize},
      ybar,
      bar width = .8cm
    ]
    \addplot coordinates {(Spugna 1,0.56) (Spugna 2,2.84) (Spugna 3,3.57) (Spugna 4,5.45) (Spugna 5,1.12) (Spugna 6,4.29)};
    \addplot coordinates {(Spugna 1,0.66) (Spugna 2,3.10) (Spugna 3,3.77) (Spugna 4,5.61) (Spugna 5,1.27) (Spugna 6,4.27)};
    \legend{Reali,Fitting}
  \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
```