# How can I remove gaps in histogram comparing graphs?

Tags: pgfplots, gap

If possible I want to draw following simple histogram, where there is no much gap in between.

[image]

When I try (original code is taken from: [PGFPlots histogram not showing all series](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/389403/pgfplots-histogram-not-showing-all-series)):

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

 \sisetup{
  round-mode          = places,
  round-precision     = 2,
  }

  \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      x tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
      ylabel={\small{Efficienza (\milli\gram\per\gram)}},
      width = 15.4cm, height = 10.7cm,
      legend style={
        font=\scriptsize,
        cells={anchor=west}
      },
      legend pos=north west,
      symbolic x coords={Spugna 1,Spugna 2},
      xtick=data,
      tick label style={font=\scriptsize},
      ybar,
      bar width = .8cm
    ]
    \addplot coordinates {(Spugna 1,0.56) (Spugna 2,2.84)  };
    \addplot coordinates {(Spugna 1,0.66) (Spugna 2,3.10)  };
    \legend{Reali,Fitting}
  \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get following output:

[image]

---

The histogram looks nicely when it has multiple comparing labels like https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82373/127048.

But if there is two-three compared histograms, there is a huge gap in between like I am having. How can I remove the gap in between and make it look more compact.

Comment: You can try `enlarge x limits=0.5` or something similar. Unrelated: You should get an error which can be solved by replacing `\milli\gram\per\gram` by `\unit{\milli\gram\per\gram}`.

Comment: @JasperHabicht `enlarge x limits=0.8` and also using `width = 6cm` help me to solve it.